# Chrome & Firefox interpret url() differently, making .replace() regex challenging

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

The following needs to remove `url('` portion of string, previously returned from `.css('background-image')` on an element object in the DOM, which works perfectly well in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

```
// example value of artworkURL: url('http://somewebsite/picture.jpg')
artworkURL = artworkURL.replace(/url\(\'/g,'');
```

I discovered this was because Chrome removes the `''` from `url('picture.jpg')` however, removing `\'` from the regular expression causes Firefox to then break, because Firefox replaced `''` with `""` but still understands the regular expression. Even the removal of parenthesis in the CSS causes Firefox to render `""` back in.

How do I keep both browsers and their various compliance happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
artworkURL = artworkURL.replace(/url\(['"]?/g,'');
```

This will remove the `'` if it it present, and even takes into account browsers that might use `"` instead. A similar regex can be used for removing the end:

```
artworkURL = artworkURL.replace(/['"]?)/g,'');
```

Comment: Thank Kolink, this looks like it should do the trick. Chrome seems to be caching assets recently (I added in some console logging to check your patterns, and those logs aren't happening in Chrome, but are in Firefox) so I'll come back once Chrome starts behaving itself. Been having a few Chrome related issues of late...

Comment: Chrome's caching hissy fit is over, and it works great, thanks Kolink.